# Why is my for loop not re-evaluating condition after 'continue'?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, continue

I am learning js and I can't figure out why my loop isn't working. pos is an object {i, j}. I want the loop to start at pos.i-1 until pos.i+1 and the same for j. Board is a matrix(table) and the if statements are to make sure the i and j values don't go beyond the matrix size and that the cell in the given position is skipped. The problem is when the code gets to 'continue' it does i++ or j++ but doesn't return to the condition in the for loop and just keeps going. I would love to know why that is and what I can do to make it work the way I need it to.

```js
function expandShown(board, pos) {
    for (var i = pos.i - 1; i <= pos.i + 1; i++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= board.length) continue;

        for (var j = pos.j - 1; j <= pos.j + 1; j++) {
            if (j < 0 || j >= board.length) continue;
            if (i === pos.i && j === pos.j) continue;

            var currCell = board[i][j];
            if (!currCell.isShown) {
                currCell.isShown = true;
                gGame.shownCount++;
                var cellToRender = document.querySelector(`#cell-${i}-${j}`);
                var strToRender = (currCell.isMine) ? MINE : currCell.minesAroundCount;
                renderCell(cellToRender, strToRender);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After `continue` it goes to next iteration in loop. So the code block after continue will not be executed.

Comment: Can you include the inputs to `expandShown` so as to make this a [mcve]

Comment: I don't want to execute the code block after continue, I want it to go to the next iteration as long as it still falls under the condition in the for loop, but for some reason it just keeps adding to the 'i' and 'j'

Comment: @Jamiec sure! the board is an 8*8 matrix (array of arrays) and pos is {2,2} for example

Comment: I mean _actual values_.

Comment: "*when the code gets to 'continue' it does i++ or j++*" - yes. "*…but doesn't return to the condition in the for loop and just keeps going*" - actually it does. If the condition is no longer met, it will end the loop. Can you please make a [mcve] that demonstrates how it "keeps going"?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how **continue** work: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_continue.asp

The continue statement breaks one iteration (in the loop) if a specified condition occurs, and continues with the next iteration in the loop.

Comment: When it goes to the next iteration, does it first get evaluated in the for loop to make sure it still falls under the condition? in this case to make sure i<=pos.i+1

Comment: okay so my question is if for example pos.i=2 , i want the loop to start at i=1 and stop at i=3, however it just keeps adding to the i without checking i<=3

Answer (score 0):

A `continue` statement is used to stop the execution of the current iteration of a loop, and jump straight to the next iteration:

> The **`continue` statement** terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.
>
> — [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Comment: When it goes to the next iteration, does it first get evaluated in the for loop to make sure it still falls under the condition? in this case to make sure i<=pos.i+1

Comment: as soon as a `continue` is reached, the current iteration stops and the next starts @AnnaHaskelsky